# SAPUI5 GeoMap add Route

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

How can I add a route to a UI5 geomap using js? I didn't find anything in the samples or the documentation.

Has it something to do with the method `addGeoJsonLayer()`?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. You have to create a VO Object as it is outlined here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/vbm/bestpractices.html

then add it using `addVo()` 
 like it is outlined here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap.html#addVo

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
var oRouteCollection = new sap.ui.vbm.Routes

next

oGeoMap.addVo(oRouteCollection);
```

Source: Sygyzmundovych
[My walk during QCon London 2018](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/kEzGKiJtuyPKGru5XdL0?p=templates&preview)